# How do i fetch/request tweets in react after authorising with passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, passport.js, twitter-oauth

i have managed to complete the authorisation stage from this github https://github.com/funador/react-auth-client where ive copied both back end nodejs and front end React files, i would like help or maybe help directing me to a site displaying how to fetch/request tweets once the callback from signing in has been executed resulting on my social media Display picture to be shown.

I have been on the twitter site and copied the code from the nodejs portion in order to try getting tweets: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/tweets-and-users/quick-starts/get-tweets

and i refactored to look like this on a separate tweet.js file to be imported into the App.js (App component). Heres my App.js code where ive imported my tweet component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import OAuth from './OAuth'
import Loading from './Loading'
import Footer from './Footer'
import Tweets from './Tweets'
import { API_URL } from './config'
import './App.css'
const socket = io(API_URL) //,{transports: ['websocket']}
const providers = ['twitter', 'google', 'facebook', 'github']

export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    loading: true
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    socket.on('connect', function(){
      console.log('connected')
    });

    fetch(`${API_URL}/wake-up`)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          this.setState({loading: false})
        }
      })
  }

  render() {
    const divStyles = {

    }
    const buttons = (providers, socket) =>
      providers.map(provider =>
        <OAuth
          provider={provider}
          key={provider}
          socket={socket}
        />
      )

    return (
      <div className='wrapper'>
        <div className='container'>
          {this.state.loading
            ? <Loading />
            : buttons(providers, socket)
          }
        </div>
{
buttons
? <Tweets provider='twitter' />
: <div> Hasnt fetched</div>
}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the tweet.js file as such:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const request = require('request');

const util = require('util')
const get= util.promisify(request.get);
const endpointURL = new URL('https://api.twitter.com/labs/1/tweets');

export default class Tweets extends Component {
state={
  tweets:''
}
componentDidMount(){
  async function getRequest(){
    const params = {
      ids: 'TLgXKh7bO0H_t9DeAAAq',
      format: 'detailed',
    };
    const req = await get({url:endpointURL, qs: params, json:true, mode: 'cors'});
    if( req.body ){
      return req.body;

    } else {
     console.log('not working working')
    }

  }

  (async ()=>{
    try{
      const response = await getRequest();
      console.log(response);
    } catch(e){
      console.error(e)
    }
  })();

  }






  render() {

    return(
      <div>
        <ul>
        {this.state.tweets
          ? this.state.tweets.map(el=>(<li>{el}</li>))
          : <div>Didnt fetch</div>}
      </ul>
    </div>
    )
  }
}


/*<div>


      </div>*/
```

Will i need a database as i am trying to display a list of several tweets i.e 10 tweets listed ? Any help would be greatly appreciated as i have been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: Please ask a single, specific question and provide a [mcve] which highlights your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am trying to create a web app that shows a wall of fetched live tweets as they happen. The user logs in their credentials as shown in the link provided above (done with the help of the passportjs authorisation), there the users tweets should be shown. I will continue to search for an example of what I am trying to do